# Cutting the cord

Tags: router, internet, cable

Getting rid of cable, getting internet only, (xfinity) have Netgear Nighthawk CM1100 DOCSIS 3.1 Cable modem on order, do I also need a wireless router? I thought this was all in one...not tech saavy here, tryin to get my ducks in a row before the cable is disconnected. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably don't need a DOCSIS 3.1 standard modem. You could get this [NETGEAR Nighthawk AC1900](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00ZUPOF7Y/?coliid=I1NBL6O1ZHQ0SB&colid=HVT1UUHVKCF4&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it) if you really want a Nighthawk model, or here is another option [Netgear C6300](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00J65WQHU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which also has a wifi router built in. Tell us what your download speed will be, and it can help further refine results.

Comment: you say "Getting rid of cable"  then you say  "Cable modem on order"  What do you mean and why do you say that?

Comment: your title "cutting the cord" is perhaps (intentionally) confusing a cable with a cable modem?   Maybe you are trying to use your title to make a joke, but that does not help anybody.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, not trying to be cute with the title. I'm getting rid of cable tv and just going with an internet connection and stream tv. Comcast, who will be my internet provider told me I needed the 3.1 modem if I didn't want to rent theirs, never mentioned a router, so I was confused on what I actually needed to make this work. I will look into the ac1800 or c3600.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Netgear Nighthawk’s documentation states that a separate router is required for WiFi.